# ASP.Net Jquery UI Autocomplete "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Tags: jquery, asp.net, autocomplete

In an ASP.net program, there is a UserControl that has a Master Page and this jquery isn't working, I get "Object doesn't support this property or method"
The paths are correct.
When I comment out the autocomplete line I get no errors.
No other js files extend autocomplete
When I have the exact code in a sample project it works!!!
It's like it can't find jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.

Ideas?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../CSS/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="../../js/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../js/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {    
    $("input#companyListDropDown").autocomplete({
        source: ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"]
       });   
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML markup excerpt, where the input 'companyListDropDown' (why would a input have dropdown in its name)...

Comment: <input type="text" id="companyListDropDown" />

Comment: because as you type it shows options based on what you type

Comment: I know samples work with you too, but anyways, this works fine - http://jsfiddle.net/FloydPink/XCpGH/

Answer (score 2):

there was more than one version of jquery loaded in the porject and that makes jquery ui freak out.
With only one version of jquery autocomplete works